# Use composed regular expression variable in awk command

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I'm trying to use regular expression in awk command, where this regular expression should be a variable, and I could change it before calling the awk command

Example:
`gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/word1|word2/' file1.log`

this worked for me, this commands prints all lines contains words1 or word2 from last "new line" to the next "new line"

What I want to do is, putting word1 and word2 in a variable and use it in gawk

for example:

regex="word1|word2"
`gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/$regex/' file1.log`

where regex can be changed depends on my program
I searched and tried many solutions but nothing worked for me

Solutions I tried:

1) regex="word1|word2";
`gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/$regex/' file1.log`

2) regex="word1|word2"
`gawk -v pat="$regex" 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/pat/' file1.log`

3) regex="word1|word2"
`gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} {pat=$regex} s~/pat/' file1.log`

4) regex="word1|word2"
`echo $regex | gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/$1/' file1.log`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

If you want to keep both the strings into a single variable and want to use as a regex in awk then following may help you on same too.

```
regex='word1|word2'
awk -v reg="$regex" 'tolower($0) ~ reg' Input_file
```

There are few points here too:

I- Since you haven't provided any data Input_file sample so couldn't test it but my gut feeling is it should work.

II- Then you have mentioned `RS` and `ORS` to `\n` in BEGIN section of `awk`, which is redundant as by default itself they are set to new line so you could remove that part from code.

Comment: Hi, This worked, but I want to use 1 variable that I can config before the awk command, since it could be in the next iteration word1, word2,word3 and word4

Comment: check my edit once, I have added variable from shell to awk which could have multiple strings in it. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @EdMorton, Apologies sir, I changed it to small letters now variable named to reg now. Thanks a TON for letting me know on same again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to input it as a compound expression you could also do this one I guess:

```
awk -v pat="$regex" '{split(regex, a, "|")}tolower($0) ~ a[1] || tolower($0) ~ a[2]'
```

Assuming your regex input of: `regex="word1|word2"`

Comment: out of the box awk has values of RS and ORS to new line, so we need not to set here in BEGIN section.

Comment: Thx for the hint :)